# Show/Hide events on fullcalendar using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm making a religious calendar for a project that shows different events for all major religions. I'm using full calendar, and I have a "religion key" at the top of the calendar, and I want to make it so that when I click, for example, Jewish, it will hide all religious events/holidays on the calendar that don't pertain to the Jewish faith. I'm having some trouble. My thinking was that I would set the ".fc-event" class in css to display:none" and then have a class called .show that would be display:block. and toggle that class / remove that class when the user clicks the menu item that pertains to the holiday. Is there a better / easier way to do this? would love some guidance/tips/help :) thank you.

Here is my code for the calendar js (using made up dates obviously):

```
events: [
        {
            title: 'xmas',
            start: '2017-03-19',
            className: 'catholic show',
            description: 'blablablablabla'
        },
        {
            title: 'Hanukkah',
            start: '2017-03-19',
            className: 'jewish show',
            description: 'blablablabla'
        },
        {
            title: 'Hindu Holiday',
            start: '2017-03-24',
            end: '2017-03-27',
            className: 'hindu show',
            description: 'blablablabla'
        }
    ]
});

$('.calendar-nav a').each(function() {

    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var x = $(this).attr('rel');

        $('.fc-event-container').each(function() {

            $(this).removeClass('show');

            if($(this).hasClass(x)) {

                $(this).addClass('show');
            }
        });
    })
});

$('.show-all a').on('click', function() {
    $('.fc-event-container').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('show')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('show');
        }
    });
});
});
```

And the php code for the calendar and calendar-key:

```
<nav class="calendar-nav">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="christianity-text"><a href="#" rel="christian">><img src="/images/calendar/christianity.png" />CHRISTIAN</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Catholic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Protestant</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Coptic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mormon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Neo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Anglican</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Celtic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jehova's Witness</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="buddhist-text"><a  href="#" rel="buddhist"><img src="/images/calendar/buddhism.png" />BUDDHIST</a></li>
    <li class="hindu-text"><a  href="#" rel="hindu"><img src="/images/calendar/hindu.png" />HINDU</a></li>
    <li class="jewish-text"><a  href="#" rel="jewish"><img src="/images/calendar/jewish.png" />JEWISH</a></li>
    <li class="islam-text"><a  href="#" rel="islam"><img src="/images/calendar/islam.png" />ISLAM</a></li>
    <li class="sikh-text"><a  href="#" rel="sikh"><img src="/images/calendar/sikh.png" />SIKH</a></li>

    <li class="pagan-text"><a  href="#" rel="pagan"><img src="/images/calendar/pagan.png" />PAGAN</a></li>
    <li class="wiccan-text"><a  href="#" rel="wiccan"><img src="/images/calendar/wiccan.png" />WICCAN</a></li>
    <li class="other-text"><a  href="#" rel="other"><img src="/images/calendar/other.png" />OTHER</a></li>
    <li class="all-text"><a href="#" rel="all">ALL</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following,

---

A. You can add/remove a class that has `display:none` and `display:block`

`$(this).addClass('hideClass');` and `$(this).addClass('showClass');`

css

```
hideClass
{ display:none; }

showClass
{ display:block; }
```

---

B. you can toggle hide and show

`$(this).hide();` and `$(this).show();`

---

C. You can change the css property itself via using [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). This is the better option, especially when you are redrawing your elements asynchronously.. the changes with the css stay.

**be warned that chrome does not support this though, which leads us to...**

---

D. Appending CSS files to override class

you can add a .css file with classes that have `!important` to override your current settings

`$("head").append("<link id='yournewcss' href='hi-res.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />");`

This is to ensure that if you redraw the page asynchronously, the property stays.

Comment: here are some other examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572157/change-css-root-variable-with-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Think this sort of thing is a lot easier to manage with CSS and a tiny bit of JS. The example below is a sort of minimal use case version but the idea is the same.

```js
/* 
Listen for clicks on the nav. Use each <a>'s "data-show"
property to determine which class to add to the #calendar.

That class, along with the CSS will determine which to show (hide, actually).

By default, all events are shown. Only when the #calendar element
gets a class associated with our CSS does anything change. 

Since we're using the :not() selector to _hide_ everything else
(instead of showing something specific) there's no need for 
any 'show all'. Once #calendar has 'show-all', the default CSS comes through.
*/

$('.calendar-nav').on('click', 'a', function(evt) {
  var showType = $(this).data('show');
  var $calendar = $('#calendar');
  if(showType !== undefined) {
    $calendar.attr('class', '').attr('class', 'show-' + showType);
  }
});
```

```css
.show-hindu li:not(.hindu),
.show-pagan li:not(.pagan) 
/* ... continue ... */ {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="calendar-nav">
  <a href="#" data-show="hindu">Hindu</a>
  <a href="#" data-show="pagan">Pagan</a>
  <a href="#" data-show="all">All</a>
</nav>

<div id="calendar">
  <ul class="events">
    <li class="hindu">Hindu 1</li>
    <li class="pagan">Pagan 1</li>
    <li class="hindu">Hindu 2</li>
    <li class="pagan">Pagan 2</li>
    <li class="hindu">Hindu 3</li>
    <li class="pagan">Pagan 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @anthony break? break how?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be add a custom attribute 'religion' to events and save it to the database. Fetch the events from the database which has the religion that you want to show:

*JavaScript:*

```
...
$.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'religion=1",
        async: false,
        success: function(response){
            json_events = response;

        }
});
$(#calendar).fullCalendar({
    events: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json_events)),

});
```

*process.php*

```
$religion = $_POST['religion'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE religion='$religion'";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to give you an advise ! I prefer doing with javascript logic .You have your event object so you can recreate object that your needed data

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var events = [
    {
        title: 'xmas',
        start: '2017-03-19',
        className: 'catholic show',
        description: 'blablablablabla'
    },
    {
        title: 'Hanukkah',
        start: '2017-03-19',
        className: 'jewish show',
        description: 'blablablabla'
    },
    {
        title: 'Hindu Holiday',
        start: '2017-03-24',
        end: '2017-03-27',
        className: 'hindu show',
        description: 'blablablabla'
    }
];
//init calendar 
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  events : events
});

$('.calendar-nav a').click(function(e) {    
        e.preventDefault();    
        var x = $(this).attr('rel');
        //if all, shows original events object
        if(x == "all") {
          newEvent = events;
        } else{
        var newEvent = checkEvent(x,events); //recreate object function
        }
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
          events : newEvent
        });
});
});

function checkEvent(x,events) {  
  var newEvent = [];
  for(var i in events) {
    var key = events[i].className.split(" ")[0];
    if(key == x) { //check same religious name
      newEvent.push(events[i]);
    }
  }
  return newEvent;
}
```