# Is it possible to change CSS Variables globally via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use CSS Variables and change them globally via jQuery.

Here is some code:

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  // Change globally "--text_color: rgb(0, 0, 255);" to for example "--text_color: rgb(0, 255, 255);"
});
```

```css
:root {
  --text_color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

div {
  color: var(--text_color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hello</div>
```

Is there a way to program this?

Would be very thankful for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change CSS root variable with jquery or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572157/change-css-root-variable-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: Hopefully, these 2 posts will be helpful to you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088655/accessing-a-css-custom-property-aka-css-variable-through-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088655/accessing-a-css-custom-property-aka-css-variable-through-javascript) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002667/change-css-variable-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002667/change-css-variable-using-jquery)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a CSS custom property (aka CSS variable) through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088655/accessing-a-css-custom-property-aka-css-variable-through-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the variable is a global, you can set it anywhere in a style and the value will be updated.

```
$("div").click(function() {
    this.setAttribute("style", "--text_color: rgb(255, 255, 255);");
});
```

However, I would suggest you don't modify the global variable but to update a class name instead. Have a list off root variables and use different values in different classes:

```
:root {
    --text-color1: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    --text-color2: rgb(0, 255, 255);
}
.class1 {
    color: var(--text-color1);
}
.class2 {
    color: var(--text-color1);
}
```

Now you can change the class name on click:

```
$("div").click(function() {
   this.className = "class2";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This has already been asked and answered.

[Change CSS variable using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002667/change-css-variable-using-jquery)

But to answer your question,

```js
$(this).get(0).style.setProperty(variable, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Append a `<style>` tag to the head. For further manipulation give it an id so you can easily remove or modify it

```js
const rules = `:root {
  --text_color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}
div {
  color: var(--text_color);
}`


$("div").click(function() {
  $('<style>', {text: rules}).appendTo('head');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe try changing the class via `addClass()` [link](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

and if you need to change it back you can use `removeClass()`[link](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

called like this (more or less)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("h1, h2, p").addClass("blue");
    $("div").addClass("important");
```

with CSS like

```
.important {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```